# How do I generate migrations for an existing database in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, entity-framework-migrations

Can I start with a database-first approach, generate a migration script from it, and then switch to a code-first approach to maintain synchronization between the code and database in .NET 6, using Entity Framework Core?

Comment: The first generated migration should contain existing tables. Then you just add new ones. Any issues with that?

Comment: That's the problem... all the approaches, I seen generates Db context from database not migrations and migrations are initialized with empty db. Can you provide some reference that generates migration from db?

Comment: Why do you want an initial migration instead of calling `EnsureCreated()`? Migrations, as the name implies, are used to *migrate* from a previous existing version to a new one.

Comment: Primarily, I need it for ongoing dev changes. Instead of altering the db, sync entities, sync db context. It would be easier to make change in the migration script and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF6, you had `–IgnoreChanges` which allowed you to create a migration for an existing database and apply it, with no changes.

In EF Core, this still [hasn't been implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2167).

What you need to do is:

1. run `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef`
2. run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`
3. open the new migration script
4. comment out the contents of the `Up` and `Down` methods to prevent any changes to your current database
5. apply it using `dotnet ef database update` , which creates the migrations table & adds an entry to the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table
6. uncomment the contents of the `Up` and `Down` methods, which ensures that if these migrations are applied to a new database, you'll also have an exact mirror of your current database's schema (and any future migrations that you apply against it)